# Request to get a key for 7,200 calls an hour (120 calls per minute) to Federal Electoral Commission API

Tags: openfec

After extracting 2000 records. 100 per page, the [Federal Electoral Commission](https://www.fec.gov/) (FEC) [API](https://api.open.fec.gov/developers/) throws an error given below. According to the documentation it ought to accept up to 1000 requests per hour with the generic API. I need to overcome the issue so I get data without the "Max retries" exception. Is there limits on endpoints requests too?

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open.fec.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/schedules/schedule_a/?api_key=mCf2MXteY3H3GcpZmqL1uVTacWEe5eiW3OWFQgBQ&sort_hide_null=false&sort_nulls_last=false&data_type=processed&committee_id=C00540302&committee_id=C00580399&committee_id=C00703975&committee_id=C00833392&committee_id=C00833913&committee_id=C00836544&committee_id=C00839365&committee_id=C00841130&committee_id=C00842237&committee_id=C00842302&two_year_transaction_period=2024&min_date=01%2F01%2F2023&max_date=05%2F30%2F2023&sort=-contribution_receipt_date&per_page=100&last_index=4071820231753777371&last_contribution_receipt_date=2023-05-30T00%3A00%3A00 (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Comment: The error seems to indicate a problem with a proxy server. Are you using a proxy server or going through a firewall?